# HTML5 Draggable ghost image not always displaying in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, draggable

I have Chrome on my laptop and one on my desktop.  They're the exact same version and they appear to have the same settings.  But when I drag on my laptop, the ghost image appears.  When I drag on my desktop, the ghost image does NOT appear.

For example, [using this demo](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop), when I drag the image on my laptop I see the ghost of the logo moving with the cursor.  On my desktop, I don't see it.  If they were different browsers or versions I could understand it, but they're the same version, so who is controlling whether or not the ghost image appears?  Is there a setting or could it possibly be an OS difference (they're both Windows, but one is 7 the other is server)?

Edit: Same odd behavior in the same version of Firefox.  The ghost is absent on one machine and present on the other.  IE the ghost doesn't appear on either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that the difference between your two setups is that one is running with Windows Aero desktop composition on and the other is not. If you take your Windows 7 desktop install and switch it to "Classic" desktop (Right Click on Desktop > Personalize > Basic and High Contrast Themes > Windows Classic) the drag ghost will stop working in Chrome on Windows 7. Why Chrome needs Aero for the drag ghost to work I'm not sure.

IE10 and Opera also do not show the ghost image when running in Classic desktop mode.

Comment: The "Windows 7 Basic" theme also allows the drag ghost to appear so the issue is isolated to systems running with the "Windows Classic" theme on.

Comment: Here is additional information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25851579/on-microsoft-windows-when-using-html5-drag-and-drop-i-do-see-the-drag-icon-gh/25851580#25851580