# On Microsoft Windows, when using HTML5 drag and drop, I do see the drag icon (ghost image) when during dragging in drag and drop

Tags: javascript, html, dom, drag-and-drop

I am using HTML5 drag and drip. During drag & drop (DnD) on Windows 7, I do not see a ghost image when I am dragging an item. It affects all browsers. How do I get it to show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need theme services running. Here is how you do that.

Start -> All Progam -> Administrative Tools -> Component Services -> Services (Local) -> Theme (Local)

Comment: Incredible, you answered your own question within 1 second!

Comment: @Mardoxx: No, was days and not a second. A QA guy found it after we both spent a long time working on this problem. I posted it hear so that others do not go through this nightmare.